# Saiku Multiple Queries | Slowness

Tags: mondrian, saiku

I am facing slowness problem on Saiku, after digging a bit into it, i found out

1. Saiku fires one query for each dimension in the mondrian cube, it tries to calculate all the measures against each dimension.
2. These results cannot be used in the final report which gets displayed, so I don't know why Saiku is doing it.
3. To get the final report it does fire a single query with all the dimensions and measure.

   - How do I stop saiku to fire intermediatte queries and have it fire only the final required query?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button "**Automatic execution**" in Saiku. after just click in "**Run query**" to run your query.

[image]